# POST method in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, post

I have an html file named index.html, in which I have a header reference to javascript file(graph.js). There is a submit button on my html page. Method attribute of my form is post.

There is a list named adj_list in my graph.js. How can I get the adj_list in my python class's post method? (I don't know how to pass adj_list with url.something like below..)

```
<form name="graph" action="/sign?.." method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

The appengine docs include getting started guides for both java and python. The tutorial shows how to handle a request form.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/

specifically:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/handlingforms.html

Comment: Hi Brian, I am already using it, and read that carefully. But I didn't got any clue. Now I am thinking of sending the value using Jquery post method. I hope that will work!